# RoR Array Formatting, remove a collect from double dimension array hash,i.e. POP out a particular array from an array using the key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have this array:

```
array_hash = [
  {
    "array_value" => 1,
    "other_values" => "whatever",
    "inner_value" => [
      {"iwantthis" => "forFirst"},
      {"iwantthis2" => "forFirst2"},
      {"iwantthis3" => "forFirst3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "array_value" => 2,
    "other_values" => "whatever2",
    "inner_value" => [
      {"iwantthis" => "forSecond"},
      {"iwantthis2" => "forSecond2"},
      {"iwantthis3" => "forSecond3"}
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to pop out "inner_value" from this to some other array.

So I want a separate array for inner_value in the following format:

```
inner_value_array = [
  {"iwantthis" => "forFirst"},
  {"iwantthis2" => "forFirst2"},
  {"iwantthis3" => "forFirst3"},
  {"iwantthis" => "forSecond"},
  {"iwantthis2" => "forSecond2"},
  {"iwantthis3" => "forSecond3"}
]
```

Now I don't need inner_value from original array_hash, so it can be deleted. So original array_hash should look like this:

```
array_hash = [
  {
    "array_value" => 1,
    "other_values" => "whatever"
  },
  {
    "array_value" => 2,
    "other_values" => "whatever2"
  },
]
```

I have tried the following:

```
inner_value_array = array_hash.collect{|d| d["inner_value"] }
```

It works great and fast for 100s of values, but it doesn't remove the inner_value, althought I don't really care if its removed but that would be taking useless memory , so is there an efficient way to pop that inner_value out from that array_hash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest thing I could think of:

```
inner_value_array = array_hash.inject([]) {|result,h| result << h.delete("inner_value") }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `flat_map`

```
array_hash.flat_map{ |k| k['inner_value'] }
#=> [{"iwantthis"=>"forFirst"}, {"iwantthis2"=>"forFirst2"}, {"iwantthis3"=>"forFirst3"}, {"iwantthis"=>"forSecond"}, {"iwantthis2"=>"forSecond2"}, {"iwantthis3"=>"forSecond3"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
only_inner = []
array_hash.each {|h| only_inner << h.delete('inner_value') } # Remove the inner value and store in the only_inner array
only_inner.flatten # Combine all inner values
```